How to Integrate User Authentication for OpenAI API in a Google Chrome Extension
I am developing a Google Chrome extension that requires users to log in to their ChatGPT (OpenAI) account. Once authenticated, the extension will use their account credentials to call the OpenAI API, rather than using credentials tied to my own account.
The extension will primarily be used to send queries to the OpenAI API and display the responses to the user.
What I’ve Tried:
Reading the OpenAI API documentation for authentication methods.
Exploring Chrome extension APIs for secure storage options, such as chrome.storage.local and chrome.storage.sync.
Looking into OAuth flows but unsure how to implement this within a Chrome extension environment.
